# read content of file type php from a table in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, file, file-upload

I created a table in database named file

```
CREATE TABLE `file` (

    `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `type` varchar(255) NULL,
    `content` varchar(255) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`name`)

)ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

but I want when I get record of a specific  file type, open the content of this file

for example:

**name:** test   **type:** php **content:**`<?php echo "hello world" ?>`

and append it as hello world in a page

thanks :)

Comment: What are you trying to do actually? How do you call it?

Comment: You just need to use **require_once** (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php) function with **mysql_result** (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-result.php) functions result ;)

Comment: So you want to append the output that he php file generates or the content of the file (*which could be anything, base64 encoded or binary as well*)

Comment: yes i want show the result in output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming I understand the question correctly and your want to run whatever code your PHP content has:
You can basically do this using two methods, but **I wouldn't recommend either**:

1. Use `eval()`. This is a very simple solution but also a very bad idea, and it won't work on many shared servers.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php

2. Write the content field to an actual PHP file (if it's not in a file already) and get the contents of that file using `file_get_contents()` or similar. You need to put the URL of the file so you only get the output, and this also won't work on some shared servers.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

Comment: is there a missing ov security by using this technique ?

Comment: Both techniques are considered bad practice, and both can be bad for security if you misuse them. Running any code without filtration is very bad for security in the first place, but if you combine it with eval(), that's a really dangerous combination. If someone can inject data into your content field, they can literally run any PHP code on your server. In shared servers eval() is usually blocked and you can't use it at all.